# Can any one explain me the given code snippet? What it does?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
    /** Create curried handleError function that already knows the service name */
      createHandleError = (serviceName = '') =><T>
        (operation = 'operation', result = {} as T) => this.handleError(serviceName, operation, result);
```

I did not understand the section

```
=><T> (operation = 'operation', result = {} as T)
```

Comment: The comment there has the term you are looking for -> "currying". Search for currying and partial application.

Answer (score 4):

`createHandleError` is a function that returns a generic function.

`(serviceName = '') => /* body here */` is the signature of the first function, which returns a second function which happens to be a generic function

```
<T>(operation = 'operation', result = {} as T) => /* body here */
```

The `<T>` is the generic parameter list, followed by the function argument list, which contains 2 arguments, both of which have default values (`operation = 'operation'` and `result = {} as T`)

Answer (score 0):

Here, what you have is a [curried function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36321/5349542) written using the relatively newer *arrow function* syntax. In short what a *curried function* does is, it returns another function when called.

The name of *curried* function is *createHandleError*, which accepts a single parameter named *serviceName*. The parameter (*serviceName*) has a default value set to it as `(serviceName = '')`. An empty string `''` is the default value of service name.

So, calling *createHandleError* will return an another function which will accept two parameters namely *operation* and *result* (these also have default value allocated to it) and  is to show generic parameter list (Just a type). And then it calls *handleError* function and passes all three parameters to it ie `(serviceName, operation, result)`.

You can call *createHandleError* like this:

```
let intermediateCreateHandleErrorFunction = createHandleError("nameOfTheService");
intermediateCreateHandleErrorFunction(someOperation, someResult);
```

Also, you can call *createHandleError* like this:

```
createHandleError("nameOfTheService")(someOperation, someResult);
```